# ng serve throwing an error in angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to run an angular application with `ng serve` it is giving me the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/_styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!.
/node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/app/shared/_styles.scss)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: 
D:\AngularProj\theme\cover\_form.scss:111:4: Can't resolve 
'./assets/theme/select.png' in 'D:\AngularProj\src\app\shared'
```

after the modification as suggested in the comment the new error is

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss ./node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css ./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css ./src/assets/iconfonts/iconfont.css ./src/app/shared/_styles.scss ./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\AngularProj/node_modules\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less' in 'D:\AngularProj
```

Comment: the url to access to your select.png is wrong as given your url you are trying to access an assets folder inside `src/app` but the assets folder of the application is just inside `src`

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I have resolved that but above error is coming

Comment: try to resolve the error : `D:\AngularProj/node_modules\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less`. Does this path exist on your project?

Comment: @GérômeGrignon There is no `less` folder in `bootstrap` folder

Comment: is this path included in your codebase somewhere (inside the styles array of your angular.json file for example? Then remove it and change it to the scss version provided by the library : node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first error message, you need to fix the path as currently it means you are searching for the assets folder inside `src/app` rather than in `src` where it lives by default.

About the second error message, there is no less folder/file in `node_modules/boostrap` folder.